# How to find the difference between two multidimentional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array in the form like

```
Array
(
    [83YaO] => Array
        (
            [0] => admin@gmail.com
        )
    [78hk0] => Array
        (
            [0] => vero@gmail.com
        )

)
```

and another array in the form

```
Array
(
    [83YaO] => Array
        (
            [0] => admin@gmail.com
            [1] => asdsad@gmail.com
            [2] => singh@gmail.com
        )
)
```

How can I find differences to add a contact like

```
Array
(
    [83YaO] => Array
        (
            [0] => admin@gmail.com
            [1] => singh.pratibha1432@gmail.com
        )
    [78hk0] => Array
        (
            [0] => vero@gmail.com
        )
)
```

and to rejected a contact like this:

```
[83YaO] => Array
    (
        [0] => admin@gmail.com
    )
```

Comment: Use [`array_diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) or [`array_diff_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php)

Comment: this is not working i already tried this

Comment: Show us what you've tried, then

Answer (score 1):

Compares array1 against array2 or more other arrays and returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");


$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: but this is not in the same manner that i want! it's just a normal array but i want it to implement it as the same manner i described above how can i achieve this?

Comment: @Veronica99 see  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php scroll down to functions same in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php